# Golang: Read single XML document from net.Conn

Tags: xml, parsing, networking, go, xml-parsing

I have a client-server connection. They communicate through xml and multiple xml documents are transmitted during one session. `xml.Unmarshal` wants a slice of bytes, but I can't just `ReadAll` all bytes from socket (it will try to read more then a single xml and therefore block).

**Is there a standard xml parser or a library, that can parse from a stream of bytes and read no more data than it actually needs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`xml.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) from the standard library for this purpose. You may use [`xml.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#NewDecoder) to create a new `xml.Decoder` which expects an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) to read the data from. [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) qualifies as it implements `io.Reader`. The [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Decode) method will read and process 1 XML document.

Let's see an example. The source will contain 2 XML documents concatenated, and we call `Decoder.Decode()` twice to read and parse those 2 documents.

The XML source: 2 XML documents (2 `<Person>`):

```
const data = `<Person>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Alice</Name>
    <Age>21</Age>
</Person>
`
```

Go struct to model the XML documents:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

Code to read those 2 XML documents:

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(data))
d := xml.NewDecoder(buf)

for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    p := Person{}
    if err := d.Decode(&p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6gxDi5v9FK)):

```
{Name:Bob Age:23}
{Name:Alice Age:21}
```

Note that `Decoder.Decode()` will return `io.EOF` if no more data is available. To read all XML documents from the input, you may do it like this:

```
for {
    p := Person{}
    if err := d.Decode(&p); err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("EOF, breaking")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p)
    }
}
```

#### Back to your example

If you want to read XML documents transmitted over a TCP connection, you may simply pass the `net.Conn` value (which implements `io.Reader`) to `xml.NewDecoder()`:

```
var con net.Conn
// Initialize / obtain connection

d := xml.NewDecoder(con)
var doc YourDocType
if err := d.Decode(&doc); err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return
}
// No error, use doc:
fmt.Printf("%+v", doc)
```